# Akka recommend pratice to init `PersistentActor`

Tags: scala, akka, akka-persistence

```
case class State(id: Long, remain: Int) {
  def take(t: Take) = copy(remain = remain - t.amount) 
}

object StateService {
  def getInitState(id: Long): Future[State]
}

sealed trait Evt
case class Init(id: Long) extends Evt
case class Take(id: Long, amount: Int) extends Evt

class FooActor extends PersistentActor  {
  var state: State

  def receiveCommand = {
    case Init(id) => ??? // how to
    case t: Take => persistAsync(t) {case e => state = state.take(t)}
  }
}

object FooActor {

}
```

As example described

How could I init the actor state before accepting any other commands ?

Comment: I think I don't get your question, why do you want to keep a `State` var around? you could just call `persist` with the event and the update method and that would be taken care of or am I missing something?

Comment: @EndeNeu `state` is planned for `futher` usage, as I have updated in the example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use different behaviors:

```
case class State(id: Long, remain: Int)

object StateService {
  def getInitState(id: Long): Future[State]
}

sealed trait Evt
case class Init(id: Long) extends Evt

class FooActor extends PersistentActor  {
  var state: State

  import akka.pattern.pipe

  def notInitialized: Receive = {
    case Init(id) => 
      // for simplicity, failure is not handled
      StateService.getInitState(id) pipeTo self
    case st: State =>
      state = st
      context become initialized
  }

  def initialized: Receive = {
    case _ => // meh
  }

  def receiveCommand = notInitialized
}

object FooActor {

}
```

You can even remove the mutable state altogether by passing it as parameters to the `initialized` behavior (e.g. `initialized(state)`).
And regarding the recovery, from official Akka docs:

> It's also possible to switch between different command handlers during
>   normal processing and recovery with context.become() and
>   context.unbecome(). To get the actor into the same state after
>   recovery you need to take special care to perform the same state
>   transitions with become and unbecome in the receiveRecover method as
>   you would have done in the command handler. Note that when using
>   become from receiveRecover it will still only use the receiveRecover
>   behavior when replaying the events. When replay is completed it will
>   use the new behavior.

Comment: Will `context.become` affect the `recovery` process ?

Comment: Nope. You can safely use `context.become` during recovery to set the initial behavior of the actor. See the edit.